# Can't make to work an imported js library inside laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, infinite-scroll

I am trying to get to work the infinity stroller by [this tutorial](https://laraget.com/blog/implementing-infinite-scroll-pagination-using-laravel-and-jscroll)

I have put the file `jquery.jscroll.min.js` inside `resources/assets/js` I have laso put this code just before the closing `body` tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.jscroll.min.js') }}"></script>
```

*Side question, Do I have to include jQuery in Laravel I was thinking jQuery is included?*

Anyway Inside my app.js I have put

```
$('ul.pagination').hide();
$(function() {
    $('.infinite-scroll').jscroll({
        autoTrigger: true,
        loadingHtml: '<img class="center-block" src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />',
        padding: 0,
        nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
        contentSelector: 'div.infinite-scroll',
        callback: function() {
            $('ul.pagination').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

then I have ran `npm i laravel-mix`, then `npm install`. Inside my webpack.mix.js I have put

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.js('resources/assets/js/jquery.jscroll.min.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

and finally I run `npm run dev`

I am getting this error `TypeError: $(...).jscroll is not a function /js/app.js:6866`

Which means Laravel have no clue about the jquery.jscroll.min.js file, but i can see that both files app.js and jquery.jscroll.min.js have been build successfully inside the public/js folder. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: check the network tab, see if the library load correctly

Comment: You need to put the scroll JS file in `/public/js/`

Comment: @madalinivascu, it is loading correctly i think: `Request URL: https://share.dev/js/jquery.jscroll.min.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200  (from memory cache)
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Comment: @Derek, isn't it what I am doing when running the `npm run dev` command. Building the 2 files inside the `/public/js/` folder. There are there I can see then and i can open them.

Comment: why are you building the files with npm?

Comment: @madalinivascu, because i wanna use Vue